# заполнить pdf при помощи формы на сайте?

Tags: php, javascript, email, pdf, forms

Реализовывал ли кто-то создание `PDF` файлов с данными пользователя, которые тот указал в форме на сайте? Т.е Пользователь оставил данные - под него сгенерировался пдф файл и ушел к нему на почту.

PS. Пока я нашел либо под названием `FPDF` которая позволяет при помощи php формировать pdf файлы... http://www.uamedwed.com/blog/web/fpdf-biblioteka-dlja-sozdanija-pdf-fajlov-na-php.html

PPS. Нашел еще вариант с JS https://habrahabr.ru/post/132611/ , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4RxSioS6Dw

PPPS. Реализовал используя бд и dompdf, ссылку на гит, выставлю позже.

Comment: юзал `dompdf` переводит сгенерированный html в pdf.

Comment: вот и я тоже думаю, сначала генерить htmlку а из неё уже в pdf ...

Comment: у dompdf там шляпа была какая-то с кириллическими символами, но вроде решается. зы: первая ссылка про js не о том, там внедрение js в тело pdf документа, а не его формирование